# Why try_files directive missing slash between root and filename?

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I'm trying to set up Nginx to work as reverse proxy, but also handle single static page (greeting) by its own:

```
root /usr/share/project/;
location = / {
    try_files index.html =404;
}
```

This config always return 404. When I tried to figure out what exactly happens I rewrite try_files directive to make it fail:

```
try_files index.html index.html;
```

And was surprised at what I saw in the error.log:

> 2019/05/07 17:30:39 [error] 9393#9393: *1 open() "/usr/share/projectindex.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 10.25.88.214, server: , request: "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1"

As you can see result file name is projectindex.html. Slash was missed. I'm trying to add / and ./ in different places but it did not lead to anything.

Finally I replace my config by following:

```
root /usr/share/project/;
location = / {
    try_files /index.html =404;
}
location = /index.html {
}
```

and it works.

I do not understand what is wrong with the first config. And also I do not understand the meaning of an empty location:

```
location = /index.html {
}
```

and why it works properly.

Maybe there is a better way to do the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`root` can optionally take a trailing `/` - it doesn't matter and it is ignored.

The *file* elements of a `try_files` statement (as with all URIs in Nginx) require a leading `/`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.

For example:

```
root /usr/share/project;
location = / {
    try_files /index.html =404;
}
location / {
    proxy_pass ...;
}
```

This works because the URI is internally rewritten to `/index.html` and processed within the **same location**.

---

If you use the `index` directive, the URI is internally rewritten to `/index.html` and Nginx will search of a matching location to process the request. In this case, you need another location to process the request.

For example:

```
root /usr/share/project;
location = / {
    index index.html;
}
location = /index.html {
}
location / {
    proxy_pass ...;
}
```

The empty location block inherits the value of `root` from the outer block. The `index` statement is the default value anyway, so strictly speaking, you do not need to specify that statement either. Notice that the values of the `index` directive **do not** require a leading `/`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_index_module.html#index) for details.